# How to increase merchanidising revenue in Football Manager 2014?

Tags: football-manager-2014

I'm playing a game with Steaua Bucharest and my eventual goal is to win the UEFA Champions League. The problem is that I really need to increase my revenues in order to afford the top quality players. Currently, my merchandising revenue is pretty low (around 150k euro per month if I remember correctly).

So, what exactly influences the merchandising revenue:

- How do feeder clubs work? Do I only need to find one, or do I need to loan a player from them etc.?
- Does playing friendlies in high population countries like China and India help?
- Does arranging friendlies with top quality teams help?

Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to increase the revenue from merchandising. There's plenty of ways to bring in money.

- You can ask your board to find you a feeder club specifically for
  bringing in revenue.
- The same can be done with a parent club. You'll get an annual fee from any parent club        you may have, so the more the better.
- You can arrange a friendly on nearly every day of pre-season. Playing against bigger clubs will get you more income. Utilise your young players and reserves in these games to stop your first team players from being unfit come the start of the season.
- Signing marquee players (even old ones) can produce a spike in merchandising.

Comment: A friend of mine told me that at Man Utd Kawaga always had the highest number of jerseys sold on the 2014 game so maybe there is something in signing Japanese players

Comment: Where did this friend get the proof? There's no breakdown of jersey sales, so I'd say this is nothing more than speculation.

Comment: More info: http://community.sigames.com/showthread.php/260442-Player-reputation-and-merchandising.

Comment: Those posts are 2011 though it surely has changed since?

Comment: Most of the financial stuff hasn't changed a lot in the last few years.

Comment: Oh ok I may check that out tonight and see if I can find what he was talking about, although it sounds like he was talking rubbish!